# Installing Solr 5.2.1 on Tomcat 7 on windows machine

Tags: solr

I want to deploy Solr 5.2.1 to tomcat 7 on a windows.Can you please provide me step by step guide to installing the same.

Comment: Have a read in the [official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr).

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Installing+Solr

Comment: These do not provide me a step by step guide on installing the same.Can any one provide me step by step guide.

Comment: 5.x not going to be under Tomcat --> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr team has discontinued support of Tomcat for newer versions.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Running+Solr+on+Tomcat